# Rspec could not find require package from puppet, can I skip require in define type?

Tags: rspec, puppet

I am trying to write rspec test the puppet code. In my puppet, I called a define type which is not part of this class. (previously defined) The puppet code works find in branch test, but rspec could not pass the "reuire".
Puppet:

```
$gluster_path = '/usr/libexec/zabbix-gluster'
  $gluster_discovery_script = "${gluster_path}/gstatus_discovery.py"
  $user_param_lines = [
    "UserParameter=gluster_volume_info[*],${gluster_discovery_script} \$1 \$2\n",
    "UserParameter=gluster_storage_info[*],${gluster_discovery_script} \$1\n",
    "UserParameter=gluster_volume_name.discovery,${gluster_discovery_script}\n",
  ]
...
zabbix::agent::userparam { 'glusterfs':
    content => join($user_param_lines, ''),
  }
```

Rspec:

```
...
 it {
    is_expected.to contain_zabbix__agent__userparam('cnvr-zabbix-gluster')
  }
```

define type:

```
define zabbix::agent::userparam($content = undef, $source = undef) {
...
  file { "/etc/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.d/userparameter_${title}.conf":
...
    require => [
        Package['zabbix-agent'],
        File['zabbix_agentd_dir'],
      ],
    content => $content,
    source  => $_source,
    notify  => Service['zabbix-agent'],
  }
```

The zabbix-agent has been installed from other modules. But error keeps prompting:

Puppet::Error:
Could not find resource 'Package[zabbix-agent]' in parameter 'require' (file: /home/edwu/puppet/modules/zabbix/manifests/agent/userparam.pp, line: 17) on node

Is there a way I can skip this requirement checking in rspec?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way I can skip this requirement checking in rspec?

The error reported in the RSpec test is a catalog compilation error.  It is in no way specific to RSpec.  Indeed, it is pointing to a *bona fide* weakness in `zabbix::agent::userparam`, and a resulting probable flaw in your class under test.  This is *precisely* one of the reasons for writing RSpec tests!

The issue is that `zabbix::agent::userparam` does not stand independently.  It requires `Package['zabbix-agent']` to be declared, but it neither declares it itself nor declares a class that does.  Your class under test inherits this weakness, though the farther you get from the the center of the issue, the more you have to lean toward calling it a bug, as opposed to simply a weakness.  Your class, too, could declare the needed other class, and it probably should do.

You cannot cause the catalog builder to let a requirement on a non-existent resource pass unremarked, nor should you want to do, because this is among the kinds of things that you *want* your tests to reveal to you.  But if you want to allow this weakness in your class to persist, then you can use [an RSpec pre-condition](https://rspec-puppet.com/documentation/classes/#specifying-code-to-include-before) to make RSpec declare the appropriate class for you, so that the requirement is actually satisfied.

Comment: Thank you @John for detail explanations. I added let(:pre_condition) on top of the spec to cover any possible classes that may require, with "include zabbix::agent", "include other::classes", .... As you said, these are the weakness of zabbix::agent::userparam. Appreciate your explanations.